# Не получается создать .exe файл с помощью pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pyinstaller

Я создал скрипт на Python3, и хотел бы сделать из него .exe файл, но при попытке скомпилировать его при помощи команды "pyinstaller name_file.py" выдает следующую ошибку:

```
118 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0
119 INFO: Python: 3.8.2
120 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
121 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Дмитрий Попов\Desktop\telegramm_stiller\main.spec
128 INFO: UPX is not available.
132 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Дмитрий Попов\\Desktop\\telegramm_stiller',
 'C:\\Users\\Дмитрий Попов\\Desktop\\telegramm_stiller']
155 INFO: checking Analysis
156 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
156 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
163 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
191 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
6623 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
6626 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\python38\\lib'
13710 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
14017 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
14023 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\python38\python.exe
14219 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Дмитрий Попов\Desktop\telegramm_stiller\main.py
15041 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
c:\python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py:208: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if setting is None or setting is '':
30360 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook setuptools.extern.six.moves from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py'.
31412 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
31414 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
38406 INFO: Processing module hooks...
38406 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cv2.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
38416 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytest.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pyinstaller==4.0', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')())
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 720, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 667, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Дмитрий Попов\Desktop\telegramm_stiller\main.spec", line 6, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['main.py'],
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 419, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks()
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 365, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 440, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 406, in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 588, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 462, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 962, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 787, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks\hook-pytest.py", line 18, in <module>
    import pytest
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pytest-5.4.1-py3.8.egg\pytest\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import register_assert_rewrite
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pytest-5.4.1-py3.8.egg\_pytest\assertion\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import rewrite
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pytest-5.4.1-py3.8.egg\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 22, in <module>
    from _pytest._io.saferepr import saferepr
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pytest-5.4.1-py3.8.egg\_pytest\_io\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from py.io import TerminalWriter as BaseTerminalWriter  # noqa: F401
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py'
```

Я использую такие модули как Selenium, cv2, и подозреваю что ошибка может быть именно в них. Вот список модулей:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import config
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import os
import pytesseract
import cv2
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import pickle
import selenium
```

В интернете ответов не нашел. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Файл со скриптом один? Попробуйте импортировать всё, чего не видит pyinstaller в основном файле. Например, если `No module named 'py'`, в файле name_file.py пропишите `import py`. Решение не лучшее, но мне когда-то помогало.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло :))

Comment: Вынесу в ответ, пожалуй, вдруг кому ещё поможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю, почему это так работает, т.к. не потратил достаточно времени, чтобы разобраться, однако, когда в pyinstaller возникают ошибки типа `No module named '...'`, то это, скорее всего, значит, что данный модуль был подключён в другом файле (не в том, который Вы передали команде pyinstaller). В таком случае часто помогает собрать все импорты из всех имеющихся у Вас файлов (по крайней мере тех, которые создавали Вы сами) и продублировать их в том файле, который передаёте в pyinstaller. После этого, если ошибка повторится для каких-то модулей, которые импортируются не в Вами созданных файлах, а в файлах других модулей, например, просто добавляйте `import имя_недостающего_модуля` в свой "главный" файл. Часто это помогает.

Скорее всего это, конечно, костыль. Возможно, он решит не все подобные проблемы. Но какие-то решит, а потому имеет место быть.